# How to see log of a single bulk insert statement

Tags: apex, soql, developer-console, debug-logs

Is there a way to find if the user insert the records is that through bulk statement or individual insert records?

I have look DebugLog and ApexLog object but does not give me a lot of information about number of records insert in one sing insert statement.

Is that possible to even find?

for an example:

I want to know if the records inserted came through individual insert like adding records one by one going through object or was it through a bulk statement.

Comment: Did you check event logs for any cues?

Comment: EventLogFile did not give any information what i'm looking for

Comment: I checked event logs API type it gives information on user, sobject,operation type and number of rows processed in one go, is that what you need?

Comment: what object or endpoint you find those information? can you post this as answer with detail and yes that's what i'm looking for.

Comment: Done. Posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you have event logs enabled in our Org. Use [this](https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com/) heroku app to open your sandbox and then it shows downloadable CSV's of all event types. If you download event type [API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_api.htm) it gives information of organization/User/sObject/Operation/Number of records. Sample screenshots below.

[image]

There is also a trailhead [module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_download) on viewing event files in case you wish to go through

Comment: while this would work for an inbound API call to SFDC, it wouldn't tell you anything about singleton vs bulk DML done within APEX

Comment: @cropredy, if you look at rows_processed it will give you number of rows processed in a single transaction and if this user only uses the Application it gives you the hint that some bulk update done by the user through UI.

Comment: Hmm. Does Event Type API include DML done by the standard UI or an Apex controller?

Comment: @cropredy - It includes both, there is a separate event type for apex execution which includes the class and method information, there is one for lightning page views which shows UI page hits. Basically a bit of detective investigation to combine all the information may be using session keys